# Loop through categores and posts of a custom post type in WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I've created a custom post type called `faq` in WordPress and I've created a few categories for it - like "Billing" and "Shipping". My end goal is to create multiple FAQ "Posts" so I can add them to our search API. However, I'm stuck on trying to loop through the post categories and display the FAQ's under each category **if the category has FAQ posts**:

Here's my code:

```php
$category_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => "ASC",
);
$categories = get_categories( $category_args ); // Get all Categories

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

    $post_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'faq',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => -1,
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $post_args ); // Get all FAQ post_types from categories


    // Here's where I'm getting stuck: If a category has faq posts:

    // 1.) Display the category title
    // 2.) Loop through the posts 
}
```

Any ideas on how to modify this code to output like so:

```
// Billing
// - Billing Question 1
// - Billing Question 2

// Shipping
// - Shipping Question 1
// - Shipping Question 2

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code logic and see if it works.

```
// Get all categories
$category_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => "ASC",
);
$categories = get_categories( $category_args ); // Get all Categories

// Loop through each category
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    
    // Display the category title
    echo '<h2>' . $category->name . '</h2>';
    
    // Fetch all posts that has that category
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'faq',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // Get all posts
        'category__in' => $category->term_id // Filter by category
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    // Check if there are posts for this category
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        echo '<ul>';
        // Loop through the posts 
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>No posts found for this category.</p>';
    }

    // Reset post data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).